# how to always update USB through /tty/USB* command

Tags: can

I am doing slcan communication with i.mx8qm board every time when I reboot the board I need to update the USB port through command for proper communication

```
sudo slcand -o -s8 -t hw -S 3000000 /dev/ttyUSB*
```

how to keep USB port number updated every time or keep as it is

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: 18.04.5 version